# Heroku when I deploy my app online it crashes but on my local machine it works without errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, meanjs

```
Nov 04 09:50:57 eva-app-nodejs heroku/web.1:  Starting process with command `npm start` 
Nov 04 09:50:59 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:  > Eva@0.0.1 start /app 
Nov 04 09:50:59 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:  > nodemon ./bin/www 
Nov 04 09:50:59 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:  [nodemon] 1.8.1 
Nov 04 09:50:59 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:  [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs` 
Nov 04 09:50:59 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:  [nodemon] watching: *.* 
Nov 04 09:50:59 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:  [nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www` 
Nov 04 07:18:57 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:  module.js:339 
Nov 04 07:18:57 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:      throw err; 
Nov 04 07:18:57 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:      ^ 
Nov 04 07:18:57 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:  Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid' 
Nov 04 07:18:57 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15) 
Nov 04 07:18:57 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:      at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25) 
Nov 04 07:18:57 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:      at Module.require (module.js:366:17) 
Nov 04 07:18:57 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:      at require (module.js:385:17) 
Nov 04 07:18:57 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:      at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/objectid.js:9:16) 
Nov 04 07:18:57 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:      at Module._compile (module.js:425:26) 
Nov 04 07:18:57 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10) 
Nov 04 07:18:57 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:      at Module.load (module.js:356:32) 
Nov 04 07:18:57 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:      at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12) 
Nov 04 07:18:57 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:      at Module.require (module.js:366:17) 
Nov 04 07:18:57 eva-app-nodejs app/web.1:      at require (module.js:385:17)
```

When I try to puch my code to heroku it shows this error in the logs.
I can run it localy without problems, even when i reinstall all my dependencies.
mongoose version is 4.0.0

Comment: I had a problem with uploading my code to heroku. check this out: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263047/cannot-find-module-mongdb-heroku-mongoskin

Comment: @inspired I already tried removing the modules and running npm install but the result is still the same

Comment: If you remove the modules locally and run the npm install locally do you get a warning message saying: `npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency...` ? If so let me know

Comment: @inspired the only error I get is that he doesn't find python but that wasn't a problem before. It still runs perfectly local

Comment: is mongodb-core explicity defined as a dependecy in your package.json file?

Comment: @inspired no it isn't but it didn't give errors before I was able to run it on heroku before but after a push it doesn't work but I can't find why.

Comment: Can you try adding the mongodb-core as a dependency to your pacakage.json? 

`

Comment: Also did you specify node version on heroku?
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

Comment: The full build output would be more useful than this snippet.

Comment: @hunterloftis i added the full build output

Comment: @inspired I had to add the version of node, strange that it worked before without it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It worked before because the latest version of node is always changing. Last week it was bumped from 4.x to 5.x. Your app is compatible with 4.x but doesn't work on 5.x. Since your app didn't specify which version it's designed for, and Heroku just defaults to the most recent stable version, the app started failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before. Have you tried adding the version of node to heroku?

[Specify Node.js Version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version)